# Stop C# warning "Possible Null Reference Assignment" on setter which handles null values for a not nullable type

Tags: c#, null, compiler-warnings

```
public class Example
{
    public string Name
    {
        get => m_name;
        set => m_name = value ?? string.Empty; // valid to assign null cause it's handled but caused warnings
    }
    private string m_name;

    public Example(string? name)
    {
        Name = name; // CS8601 - Possible null reference assignment.
    }
}

// imagine this is setting on an instance and not the type
Example.Name = data; // CS8601 - Possible null reference assignment.
```

In the code I have a `string` type that is never null cause it the property setter converts null assignments to a default value. The compiler doesn't understand this and moans about it though.

I know I can fix some of these in the following ways:

- Put `!` after the assignment as I know better than the compiler - Don't like this as it might break due to refactorings
- In the constructor assign the backing field rather than the property - Works but duplicates the fallback code in the constructor and again means multiple places have to be updated if refactored/changed
- Change `Name` type to `string?` - Works in these cases but adds compiler warnings to all places that try to get the value, which is potentially more than set the property!

**Is there a way to fix this warning that isn't hacky?**

For example telling the setter that the assignment can be `null` or adding an attribute in the same style as `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]` that you can use on `TryGet` methods?

I can't find a fix to the problem that doesn't involve code duplication or ignoring the compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the use case for [`AllowNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.allownullattribute?view=net-7.0). The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#preconditions-allownull-and-disallownull) shows a very similar situation.

You just need to do:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

// ...

[AllowNull]
public string Name
{
    get => m_name;
    set => m_name = value ?? string.Empty;
}
```

You can then assign a nullable type to this property.

If you are setting the property instead of the field in the constructor, you should also mark the setter with `MemberNotNullAttribute` so that the static analyser can see that you have initialised all the non-nullable fields in the constructor.

```
[MemberNotNull("m_name")]
set => m_name = value ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: I knew that there would be something like that, Just didn't know what it would look like! Thanks